# Using 'GO', transactions & semi-colons

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In the code below, is the use of `GO`, transactions and semi-colons correct?

I appreciate these questions have been asked separately many times but I am struggling when using them in combination and would be thankful for any guidance.

I am unsure whether it is necessary to use transactions in this circumstance.

```
USE TestingDB
GO

DECLARE @CustomerContactID int = 278800

BEGIN TRANSACTION      

DELETE
FROM            dbo.CustomerContact
WHERE           CustomerContact_CustomerContactID = @CustomerContactID;


DELETE
FROM            dbo.CustomerContactComs
WHERE           CustomerContactComs_CustomerContactID = CustomerContactID;

DELETE
FROM            dbo.CustomerContactAddress
WHERE           CustomerContactAddress_CustomerContactID = @CustomerContactID;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Absolutely _opinion based_.

Comment: Your second delete is missing the `@` in front of `CustomerContactID` - this may be unwanted.

Comment: Your delete queries might be in the wrong order.  Whether or not a transaction is necessary depends on whether or not it's ok for only some of the queries to execute.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, if it's opinion based, it answers the primary question: no it's not necessary, and the use is correct (it's not necessarily wrong, anyway)..

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Answer (score 3):

1. The semicolons are <strike>obsolete</strike> not necessary in T-SQL (except for Common Table Expressions and Service Broker statements if those are not the first statements in a batch). <strike>So it's a matter of taste if you want to use them.</strike> But Microsoft recommends to always use them. (*See the first two comments below*)
2. The order of your `DELETE` statements seems wrong. You might at first want to delete the detail data from `CustomerContactComs` and `CustomerContactAddress` and then the `CustomerContact`
3. The transaction might be necessary if you want to avoid situations where you only delete a part of the information, e.g. only `CustomerContactComs` but not the rest.
4. That leads directly to the `GO`. You should not insert any `GO` statements between the statements in the transaction. `GO` is not part of T-SQL but is used for tools such as Management Studio to *indicate separate batches*.
   So if there is a `GO` the previous statements are send to the server as one batch. If one statement in that batch raises an error, the remaining statements of that batch will not be executed.
   But if you insert a `GO` here, the following statements would be a *new batch* and so the transaction could be *committed although a previous statement failed*, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Just a small addition to a good answer (I think the delete statements are syntactic incorrect though): it's my understanding that the semicolon will cease to be obsolete in the (near?) future, so it may be good practice to start using them anyway. It's ISO sql so it's always good to follow.

Comment: *the semicolons are obsolete* - that's wrong. Microsoft recommends to use them always. See e.g. here: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons